# Display a table with different sections having different colors

Tags: html

how can I change the background in an html table dynamically to have different sections be different colors?

I'm using MVC Razor HTML jquery C#

I can set it manually

```html
<tr style="background-color: #D7816C" >
```

but using a variable doesn't work

```html
<tr style=@bc >
```

preferably being able to set it with some logic in the foreach loop

```html
<div> @{ bc = "background-color: #8ED76C"; } </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, i can set it manually <tr style="background-color: #D7816C" >, but using a variable doesn't work <tr style=@bc >, same thing trying to do it at the td level.

Comment: preferably being able  to set it with some logic in the foreach loop ..             <div>
               @{ bc = "background-color: #8ED76C"; }
            </div>

Comment: by putting the variable in quotes, it worked (answer below). Unfortunately, I'm also working with a transposition table so I have to do it at the column level. Clunky but works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this worked, i just needed to put the variable in quotes

```
<tr style="@bc" ></tr>
```

Comment: it won't let me save the example ...  <tr style="@bc" >